# View parameterized query's SQL after setting parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

**The problem:** I am looking for a way to view a parameterized query's SQL after the parameters have been set in VBA.

What I have tried:

```vb
Public Function test()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qd = db.QueryDefs![1Para]

    qd.Parameters("ID").Value = 5

    Debug.Print qd.SQL

    Call qd.Close

End Function
```

**Actual output:**

```vb
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID = [ID]
```

**Desired output:**

```vb
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID = 5
```

I have looked for this answer online for a while but turned up nothing. That may indicate that this isn't possible but I thought I would ask here just in case there is something I missed.

Comment: If you revise the query's SQL to `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID = [pID]`, you could then do `Debug.Print Replace(qd.SQL, "[pID]", qd.Parameters("pID").Value)`  I don't know any other way to get what you want.

Comment: That is a very neat solution, though anything beyond a simple single parameter query and I don't think it would work.  I feel like what I had wanted isn't really easily, wishful thinking I guess.

Comment: Basically the problem you're up against here is that supplying parameter values does not update the query SQL to include those values.  You might look into ODBC logging or ShowPlan, but I'm not sure either of those would show you the SQL with parameter values inserted into the SQL.

Comment: @HansUp I figured that was the case, I just thought something so simple would have been implemented in the `QueryDefs` object.  It isn't an answer that I really NEED, more so something that just piqued my interested from another question.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be not really.